# Racket simple AE define-type

Tags: racket

From the book "Programming Languages: Application and Interpretation" page 6 I try to code the very first example in DrRacket

```
#lang typed/racket

(define-type AE
 [num (n number?)]
 [add (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?)]
 [sub (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?)])
```

But I get the error

```
aeinterpretter.rkt:5:2: define-type: unexpected term in: (add (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?))
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should run this example in the [PLAI](http://docs.racket-lang.org/plai/plai-scheme.html) language:

```
#lang plai

(define-type AE
 [num (n number?)]
 [add (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?)]
 [sub (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?)])
```

The [Typed Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/index.html) language is a totally different language that gives you most of the power of the base Racket language, but with a static type system. The `define-type` form in PLAI is a different notion of "type".

Comment: Ahh cheers! I wish the book had made that a tad clearer. What's up with the ? after types? It looks as though racket is unsure of types  since it keeps "questioning them" :-)

Comment: `number?` and `AE?` are *predicates*, i.e. functions that check some property (in this case "being a number", "being an AE"). It's a tradition Racket inherits from Scheme. Try `(number? 5)`, `(number? #t)` in the REPL, for example. I don't remember if it's in the book, but the "Get the Software" section on the [PLAI website](http://www.cs.brown.edu/~sk/Publications/Books/ProgLangs/2007-04-26/) explains how to run the programs in the book.

Comment: Cheers for the link. It should have been in the book IMHO. I went down the route of just googling "define-type" and ended up in some typed racket drama..

Comment: JFYI, the book & course are planned to eventually switch to using types instead of just predicates.  I have been teaching such a PLAI-variant course for a while which is probably also where you got that typed-racket reference.

Comment: @AsumuTakikawa could you explain what the (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?) do? does it check if the left hand side is an AE and also right hand side is an AE? so (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?) return either true or false? but what does it do as a whole in the define-type here?

Comment: could someone explain what the (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?) do? does it check if the left hand side is an AE and also right hand side is an AE? so (lhs AE?) (rhs AE?) return either true or false? but what does it do as a whole in the define-type here?